# Generate a range of price breaks based on minimum and maximum price

Tags: php, math

What I have is a list of products whereby I know the price of the cheapest product, and the price of the most expensive product, and the price of everything in between.

What I'm trying to do is to create a filter, and display a range of price breaks for the filter.

So for example if the cheapest product is $10 and the most expensive product is $100 I'd want to perhaps show a list saying:

```
$10 - $30
$30 - $50
$50 - $70
$70 - $90
$90 - $100
```

This is more complicated than it sounds because in the above example if the cheapest product is $10 but the next cheapest product is $40 then it doesn't make sense to have a $10 - $30 option.

Furthermore if the cheapest product was $10 and the most expensive product was $50 then you'd probably want only 2 or 3 price breaks in the list and not 5 selections. Likewise if the cheapest product was $10 and the most expensive was $1000 with lots of variation in between you'd want a bigger list of price breaks.

Here is what I have so far which only provides 2 price breaks and doesn't really address any of the issues above

```
<?php

// All available unique prices sorted in order
$prices = array(10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 25, 28, 29, 30, 31, 34, 35, 38, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 60, 61, 64, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 97, 98, 100);
$count = count($prices); // The number of unique prices
$min_price = $prices[0]; // The minimum price
$max_price = $prices[ $count - 1 ]; // The maximum price
$median_price = $prices[ (int) $count / 2 ]; // The price in the middle

echo "$min_price - $median_price\n";
echo "$median_price - $max_price\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort your aray of prices. Take elements at regular intervals along the index set, i.e. quantiles of your set of prices. Your median computation was already going in that direction. The number of quantiles to take would be fixed up front, e.g. 5 or whatever. Round the elements you find in a suitable way, e.g. by taking their base-10 logarithm, rounding that to the nearest integer, using it to round it to a number which has zeros in all digits but the most significant. Discard values which are the same after rounding. Done.